# not able to retrieve old session variable values in php

Tags: php

Hi i am new to PHP.I am having "item.php" page and "cart.php" page. In item.php 3 checkboxes are available. if i click on one checkbox from item.php the value is sent to to cart.php page. however if i go back and select another checkbox the old value is not retained. Only the new value is getting printed. 
I am storing the retrieved checkbox value in a session variable in cart.php  but still not able to retrieve the old values selected. Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Code please! It's hard to answer such questions based on vague explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have session_start( ) in your item.php page? If you're saving it via session in your cart.php page, you should have session_start( ) in your item.php page to get the session.

You can try to do this in your item.php page to check:

```
session_start( );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to start the session in item.php, too. This way you will be able to process the user's session data within both pages. In item.php you need to check if the user has selected any of your checkboxes (you can tell from their session value) and have this represented on the page.

Comment: I have set the session variable in Item.php also. But now the session variable is retrieving the previous previous value. For ex: if i had selected check1 in item.php--> moved to cart.php and again move back to item.php select check2 then in cart.php instead of getting check1 value i am getting the value that i selected before check1. i.e my previous session variable is getting retrieved. Sorry for the confusion